# Cannot Create Project in Eclipse Counterclockwise Clojure Plugin

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I just installed the Eclipse Counterclockwise Clojure Plugin, and I cannot create a new Clojure project.

The [CCW troubleshooting page here](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/wiki/TroubleShooting) says there's a way to fix this, but unfortunately the link is now broken.

When I try to create a project there are no options to select for a closure project.

Does anyone know the fix?

EDIT:  I should probably mention that I'm on eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

Comment: what version of ccw? what version of java?

Comment: make sure you're on at least java 7

Comment: @lispHK01I do have java 8 installed, but it's not the default.  I have other non-eclipse things that require 1.6.  I wonder if I can set up eclipse to use java 8...

Comment: try editing your `eclipse.ini` to tell it to use to the java 8 jvm -- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was using Java 1.6 by default.

Install Java 7 or higher or make eclipse use that vm with the -vm option in eclipse.ini.

See here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#eclipse.ini